# How to replace all occurrences of a word in unix/Linux

Tags: linux, unix, emacs

Replace a word with another including those that have a capital 
For example: replace elephant with wombat (including Elephant with Wombat)
Using single emacs command

Comment: Read `C-h i g (emacs) Replace` (or https://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replace.html if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure `case-replace` is not *nil* (which is the default):

```lisp
(let ((case-replace t))
   (replace-string "elephant" "wombat"))
```